# Select Trump today records .time()

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is how I stored them

```
INSERT INTO Trump SET code='".$name."', type='cja', whendate='".time()."'
```

Now I want to display today records.

```
SELECT * FROM Trump WHERE type='cja' AND DATE(whendate) = time(NOW()) ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5
```

Why MySQL returned an empty result set?

Comment: you are comparing `date` with time part in `WHERE` clause `DATE(whendate) = time(NOW())`, they will never be equal

Comment: Stored as timestamps? `WHERE whendate BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(START OF TODAY) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(END OF TODAY)`

Comment: Darren, how do you get beginning and end of that day?

Comment: Start -> `date("Y-m-d", time()) . "00:00:01"` & end `date("Y-m-d", time()) . " 23:59:59"`

Comment: Darren, error in your sql syntax; I go for this `BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')) ` Trump will smile..

Comment: That works too haha!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Trump SET code='".$name."', type='cja', whendate='".strtotime(Date('Y-m-d')."'
```

Then try your sql select command

```
SELECT * FROM Trump WHERE type='cja' AND whendate ='".strtotime(Date('Y-m-d')."' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5
```

will selects all the records inserted today.

Comment: Thanks but UNIX_TIMESTAMP is a must at this time.